# Poisson Distribution?? finding the probability of randomly distributed trees.

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Assume that the aggressive invasive tree known as European Buckthorn is randomly distributed in a degraded forest preserve with **λ =40** trees/seedlings per **100m^2**. If **two 100 m^2** plots are randomly chosen then what is the probability that one of the plots has at **least 30** buckthorn trees/seedlings while the other plot has **30 or less** such trees?

I guess it's Poisson distribution. However, how should it be solved when question asks to find one area with *at least 30* trees while the other area is *30 or less*? Thank you!

Comment: Are you in the section of the textbook where they talk about approximating Poisson distributions by other distributions (such as normal distributions)?  (If not, well, you only have to add up 31 probabilities.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We assume that the tree count in each plot is independent of the other.  Let $N_1, N_2 \sim {\rm Poisson}(\lambda = 40)$ be IID Poisson variables indicating the random number of such trees in each plot.  Then the desired probability is $\Pr[N_1 \ge 30 \cap N_2 \le 30] + \Pr[N_1 \le 30 \cap N_2 \ge 30].$  But because $N_1, N_2$ are IID, this probability is simply $$\begin{align*} 2 \Pr[N_1 \le 30] \Pr[N_2 \ge 30] &= 2 (\Pr[N_1 \le 30])(1 - (\Pr[N_2 \le 30] - \Pr[N_2 = 30])) \\ &= 2p\left(1 - p + e^{-40} \frac{40^{30}}{30!}\right), \end{align*}$$  where $$p = \Pr[N_1 \le 30] = e^{-40} \sum_{i=1}^{30} \frac{40^i}{i!}.$$  This gives a probability of approximately $0.118054$.

Comment: Shouldn't the final answer be **0.18465471** though, instead of 0.118054 according to your calculations?

Comment: @juknee The formula listed above evaluates to $0.118054$. (The $p$ comes out to about $0.061694$.) Are you trying to match an answer?

Comment: @tabstop: yup, that's exactly what I was trying to do. I think I got it!! Thanks!!